# How to show linenumbers for IEEE proof as one column?

Tags: ieee-style

The following is the following but I want the text is in one column, not in two:

[image]

### Reproduction of gap between linenumbers

```
\documentclass{article} % [conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 

\linenumbers
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Electron Avalanche in GEM Foils}
There are several simplifications made in simulating the electron avalanche in GEM foils. 
There is only multiplication from electron collision. 
There is no electron lost to negative ion formation. 
The space charge effects are negligible. 
%
%
\begin{equation}
Q = n_{0} e M
\end{equation}
%
where $e$ is the electron change, and $M$ is the average \emph{gas multiplication factor} that characterizes the counter operation. 

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

How can you have those small numbers at the side for the review at one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lineno` package

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[mathlines,switch]{lineno}


\title{The title}
\author{The authors}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\[x=y\]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

The package options `mathlines` puts numbers to equations and `switch` puts the numbers in the outer margin.

For one column, just switch to `article` class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}


\title{The title}
\author{The authors}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\[x=y\]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

To answer for the comment, you have to load `lineno` after `mathtools` so that the definitions of equation environments (made by `lineno`package) are not over written by `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article} % [conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}   %<---- here
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\linenumbers
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Electron Avalanche in GEM Foils}
There are several simplifications made in simulating the electron avalanche in GEM foils.
There is only multiplication from electron collision.
There is no electron lost to negative ion formation. 
The space charge effects are negligible.
%
%
\begin{equation}
Q = n_{0} e M
\end{equation}
%
where $e$ is the electron change, and $M$ is the average \emph{gas multiplication factor} that characterizes the counter operation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Masi I am not able to reproduce the result. Can you post the code that does this?

Comment: @Masi: please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Some preview of answers about [Why doesn't lineno number a paragraph when it is followed by an “align” equation environment without a space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43648/13173):

### [#1] [Some gaps of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43679/13173) and Harish's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266459/13173)

Both answer lead to surprising gaps in different contents. 
Harish's answer works in simple Mathematical environments where no new declarations is made. 
The former's code reproduced here:

```
\newcommand*\patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname oldend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
  \renewenvironment{#1}%
     {\linenomath\csname old#1\endcsname}%
     {\csname oldend#1\endcsname\endlinenomath}}% 
\newcommand*\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno[1]{%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1}%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1*}}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{equation}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{align}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{flalign}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{alignat}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{gather}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{multline}%
}
```

which skips some lines of big files, especially with Math, for example:

[image]

### #2 [Numbers everything but get clustered sometimes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55297/13173)

```
\newcommand*\patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname oldend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
  \renewenvironment{#1}%
     {\linenomath\csname old#1\endcsname}%
     {\csname oldend#1\endcsname\endlinenomath}}% 
\newcommand*\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno[1]{%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1}%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1*}}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{equation}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{align}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{flalign}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{alignat}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{gather}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{multline}%
}
```

giving sometimes clusters like

[image]

### Comments

I think *mbudisic*'s answer is most appropriate when no lines cannot be skipped, like in my case, for cooperative work. 
Partial numbering is challenging for commenting Mathematics.