# How to make these Math paragraphs more readable?

Tags: math-mode

I have a difficulty in separating paragraphs where is Math text, for instance between lines 8-9 in the output. 
One option is to have space at the beginning of the first sentence in each new paragraph.

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec

%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43648/13173
\newcommand*\patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname oldend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
  \renewenvironment{#1}%
     {\linenomath\csname old#1\endcsname}%
     {\csname oldend#1\endcsname\endlinenomath}}% 
\newcommand*\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno[1]{%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1}%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1*}}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{equation}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{align}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{flalign}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{alignat}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{gather}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{multline}%
}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\NewDocumentCommand{\normL}{ s O{} m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\norm*{#3}}{\norm[#2]{#3}}_{L_2(\Omega)}%
}

\usepackage{enumitem}   
\linenumbers
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item % do not use an empty line here 
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
\item Recall that

Then, $c_{0}$ and $c$ are linear spaces with respect to the natural operations for addition and scalar multiplication and Banach spaces with respect to the norm 
$\norm{u}_{l^{\infty}} 
= \sup\nolimits_{ j \in \mathbb{N} } \abs{ u_{j} } 
\,\,\, \forall u 
= (u_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in c_{0} \text{ or } c$. 

For $1 \leq p < +\infty$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we denote $e_{n} = (0 ... 0.1.0...) \in l_{p}$ (1 in the $n^{th}$ position). 
The notation is used for the space $c_{0}$. 
Also, for $X = l_{p}$ with $1 \leq p < \infty,$ or $c_{0}$, we define the canonical projections 
$(p_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot p_{n} : 
X \to \mathbb{K}, p_{n} (u_1, ..., u_{n}, ...) 
= u_{n} 
\, \forall (u_{1}, ..., u_{j}, ...) \in X$. 

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \leq p \leq +\infty$, we denote 
$l_{p}^{j} = ( \mathbb{K}^{n}, \norm{ \cdot }_{p} )$, 
where 
$\norm{ (u_{1}, ..., u_{n}) }_{p} 
= (\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^{n} \abs{u_{k}}^{p} )^{1/p}$ 
for $1 \leq p < \infty$ 
and 
$\norm{ (u_{1}, ..., u_{n} ) }_{\infty} 
= \max\nolimits_{1 \leq k \leq j} \abs{u_{k}}$. 

\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}    
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comments

- I use `\nolimits` within the text making the sentences maintain better the height of the line.
- The paragraphs starting at the lines 5 and 9 are difficult to separate from other text.

How can you make the text better readable? 
I think the better separation of paragraphs (by somehow adding spaces at the start of paragraphs is one option).

Comment: you don't need `\nolimits` on things like `\sum` that is automatic in inline math

Comment: no. `\sum\nolimits` is exactly the same as `\sum` in inline math, just longer to type, and harder to read the source.

Comment: There are no `\semantics` in `\nolimits`: the semanics of a summation is the same however it is laid out, it is a purely redundant visual command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paragraph spacing in latex lists is called `\parsep`. As you are already using `enumitem` this can be set with the `parsep` option. Also as noted in comments you don't need `\nolimits` here,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec

%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43648/13173
\newcommand*\patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname oldend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
  \renewenvironment{#1}%
     {\linenomath\csname old#1\endcsname}%
     {\csname oldend#1\endcsname\endlinenomath}}% 
\newcommand*\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno[1]{%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1}%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1*}}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{equation}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{align}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{flalign}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{alignat}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{gather}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{multline}%
}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\NewDocumentCommand{\normL}{ s O{} m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\norm*{#3}}{\norm[#2]{#3}}_{L_2(\Omega)}%
}

\usepackage{enumitem}   
\linenumbers
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item % do not use an empty line here 
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)},parsep=\medskipamount]
\item Recall that

Then, $c_{0}$ and $c$ are linear spaces with respect to the natural operations for addition and scalar multiplication and Banach spaces with respect to the norm 
$\norm{u}_{l^{\infty}} 
= \sup_{ j \in \mathbb{N} } \abs{ u_{j} } 
\,\,\, \forall u 
= (u_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in c_{0} \text{ or } c$. 

For $1 \leq p < +\infty$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we denote $e_{n} = (0 ... 0.1.0...) \in l_{p}$ (1 in the $n^{th}$ position). 
The notation is used for the space $c_{0}$. 
Also, for $X = l_{p}$ with $1 \leq p < \infty,$ or $c_{0}$, we define the canonical projections 
$(p_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot p_{n} : 
X \to \mathbb{K}, p_{n} (u_1, ..., u_{n}, ...) 
= u_{n} 
\, \forall (u_{1}, ..., u_{j}, ...) \in X$. 

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \leq p \leq +\infty$, we denote 
$l_{p}^{j} = ( \mathbb{K}^{n}, \norm{ \cdot }_{p} )$, 
where 
$\norm{ (u_{1}, ..., u_{n}) }_{p} 
= (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \abs{u_{k}}^{p} )^{1/p}$ 
for $1 \leq p < \infty$ 
and 
$\norm{ (u_{1}, ..., u_{n} ) }_{\infty} 
= \max_{1 \leq k \leq j} \abs{u_{k}}$. 

\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't change here but `...` should be `\dots`

Comment: I accept this answer because this do the same as Przemyslaw's command but without manual additions.

Answer (score 4):

There are standard vertical spaces: `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip`. Using them (in this case probably the first one) leaves some flexibility in creating a paragraph.

I am assuming that you don't want to set `\parskip` to some positive value globally, what may be an alternative method.

Output with two `\smallskip` and one `\medskip`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could define some bigger line spacing inside your enumerate. Not really beautiful, but well, if you think this helps for readability.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno} 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\linenumbers
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext  
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
        \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]\setstretch{1.1}
            \item Recall that\par           
            Then, $c_0$ and $c$ are linear spaces with respect to the natural operations for addition and scalar multiplication and Banach spaces with respect to the norm 
            $\norm{u}_{l^{\infty}} 
            = \sup\nolimits_{ j \in\mathbb{N}} \abs{u_j}\ \forall u 
            = (u_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in c_{0}$ or $c$.\par         
            For $1 \leq p < +\infty$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we denote $e_{n} = (0 \dots 0.1.0\dots) \in l_{p}$ ($1$ in the $n$th position). 
            The notation is used for the space $c_0$. 
            Also, for $X = l_{p}$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$, or $c_{0}$, we define the canonical projections 
            $(p_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot p_{n} : 
            X \to \mathbb{K}, p_{n} (u_1,\dots, u_{n},\dots) = u_{n}\ \forall (u_{1},\dots, u_{j},\dots) \in X$.\par
            For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \leq p \leq +\infty$, we denote 
            $l_{p}^{j} = ( \mathbb{K}^{n}, \norm{\cdot}_{p} )$, 
            where 
            $\norm{ (u_{1},\dots, u_{n})}_{p} 
            = (\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^{n} \abs{u_{k}}^{p} )^{1/p}$ 
            for $1 \leq p < \infty$ 
            and 
            $\norm{ (u_{1},\dots, u_{n})}_{\infty} 
            \linebreak = \max\nolimits_{1 \leq k \leq j} \abs{u_{k}}$.          
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}  
\blindtext  
\end{document}
```

[image]